# Could my spring program run using dispatcher-servlet.xml and without using ContextLoaderListener and applicationcontext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to run spring-orm program using `dispatcher-servlet.xml` only. Without using `ContextLoaderListener` and `applicationcontext.xml`? If yes then how?

Secondly why is it necessary to register `dispatcher-servlet.xml` or `applicationcontext.xml` in `web.xml`? Because when these files are not registered in `web.xml` all the setter injections(specified in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` or `applicationcontext.xml`) take place on server start-up that means these xml files are loading without registering in `web.xml`.

Comment: dispatcher-servlet.xml configures the context for your dispatcher servlet. I think you need to read more about Spring - the xml files aren't "registered" in web.xml, they're paramters to Spring's context loader.  How do you want to use dispatcher-servlet.xml if not to create the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run spring-orm program using dispatcher-servlet.xml only. Without using ContextLoaderListener and applicationcontext.xml?

Yes, that's fine.

> If yes then how?

You just do it.  Put everything you need into `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, it'll operate on its own. While it's common practice to put DAO-related stuff in `applicationContext.xml` and MVC stuff in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, it's by no means a requirement. It can all sit in one file if you choose.

> Secondly why is it necessary to register dispatcher-servlet.xml or applicationcontext.xml in web.xml? Because when these files are not registered in web.xml all the setter injections(specified in dispatcher-servlet.xml or applicationcontext.xml) take place on server start-up that means these xml files are loading without registering in web.xml.

Because if you don't specify them in `web.xml`, Spring will use its defaults and look for them anyway. `DispatcherServlet` will look for `<servlet-name>-servlet.xml`, and `ContextLoaderListener` will look for `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` by default.   You can override this in `web.xml` if you choose.